# using react state to update video src - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have a user provide input to a video link which will update the state value which I then use as the src for the video.

If I set the initial state to a video link then it works but I am not having luck once it is submitted with input values. 
I can see the values is being passed and I am able to display it.

Am I missing something? Here is my code

```
class Video extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.textInput = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
    }

        handleSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setState({ value: this.textInput.current.value })
        };

        render() {
            console.log(this.state)
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div className="add-video">
                        <h3>Add Your Own</h3>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                ref={this.textInput}>
                            </input>
                            <button type="submit" value="submit">Go!</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <p>Your video: {this.state.value}</p>
                    <div className="video-wrapper">

                        <video
                            maxwidth="800"
                            width="100%"
                            height="450"
                            playsInline
                            autoPlay
                            muted
                            loop
                        >
                            <source
                                src={this.state.value}
                                type="video/webm"
                            />
                        </video>

                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: um can you share what you are currently getting as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use onChange event of input element like below;

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})} />
```

And you don't need form and submit event.

If you want to show video after Go! button click you can use another flag like this;

```
this.state = {
  value: '',
  showVideo: false
};
```

And use onSubmit event like this;

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); this.setState({showVideo: true})}}>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value})} />
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

And check showVideo flag when showing video tag in your render method;

```
this.state.showVideo ? 
                        <video
                            maxwidth="800"
                            width="100%"
                            height="450"
                            playsInline
                            autoPlay
                            muted
                            loop
                        >
                            <source
                                src={this.state.value}
                                type="video/webm"
                            />
                        </video>
    : "no video"
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is it possible to do something similar with passing props on form submission?

Comment: What do you mean with form submission ?